# How to find lowercase first letter in word list, and change them into uppercase

Tags: python

I want to find out if any of those names start with lowercase and, if they do, change it to uppercase.

```
unknown_list = ('toby', 'James', 'kate', 'George', 'rick', 'Alex', 'Jein', 'medelin')
```

Comment: Given a string `s` in python, you can capitalize it using `s.capitalize()`

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `.title()` is probably more useful with names, since it upper-cases every word in a string, not just the first. In this case it doesn't matter though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tuples are immutable so you cannot change them but if you change `unknown_list` into a list then you are able to do that. You should use the `.capitalize()` function!

Here is the short version.

```
x = ['toby', 'James', 'kate', 'George', 'rick', 'Alex', 'Jein', 'medelin']
x = [name.capitalize() for name in x]
```

And the long version.

```
x = ['toby', 'James', 'kate', 'George', 'rick', 'Alex', 'Jein', 'medelin']
for index, name in enumerate(x):
     x[index] = name.capitalize()
```

The main idea in both is that you capitalize every name in order to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

The `capitalize()` method can do this easily:

```
>>> unknown_list = ('toby', 'James', 'kate', 'George', 'rick', 'Alex', 'Jein', 'medelin')

>>> new_list = [x.capitalize() for x in unknown_list]
>>> new_list
['Toby', 'James', 'Kate', 'George', 'Rick', 'Alex', 'Jein', 'Medelin']
```

Note that's creating a *new* list but you could just as easily assign back to the original variable if you want to overwrite it.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can do like this:

```
x = ['toby', 'James', 'kate', 'George', 'rick', 'Alex', 'Jein', 'medelin']
x = [name.title() for name in x]
```

Answer (score 0):

You used to chr() and ord()

```
chr(97) is 'a', chr(65) is 'A'
```

and

```
ord('a') is 97 , ord('A') is 65 as int
```

test case:

```
for name in unknown_list:
    if ord(name[0]) >=97 and ord(name[0]) <=122:
        tmp = ord(name[0]) - 32
             print(chr(tmp))
```

But, easier way

```
name = 'james'
print(name.capitalize())
```

It can print 'James'

Comment: You should have noted that this would not change anything in the list.

Comment: Yes. The only way to do this is to change the code above.

Answer (score 0):

One small reminding is that the parentheses you're using make your unknown_list a tuple. Tuples are immutable.

If you just want to capitalize everything in the list you can do this

```
unknown_list = ['toby', 'James', 'kate', 'George', 'rick', 'Alex', 'Jein', 'medelin']
capLs = []
for i in unknown_list:
  capLs.append(i.capitalize())
print(capLs)
```